# Relation between eigenvalues and size of geometrically shaped data in PCA

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, covariance, image-processing

I want to measure the orientation and size of objects in a binary image using PCA. As I have a picture the data points are gridded (pixels). The object can be either an ellipse or a rectangle that I do not know beforehand. For the centered data points I calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the covariance matrix and then want to derive the object size from the eigenvalues. The problem is that the scaling of the eigenvalues depends on the shape of the data points.

**Example**

Let's assume I have an ellipse with full axes lengths (from one end to other end) $a=100,b=50$ and a rectangle with same dimensions. Both objects are rotated by $\theta=45$ deg. from the axis aligned state, see figure.

[image: ![enter image description here]

The normalized eigenvectors direct as expected in the principal directions: $e_1\approx\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{align}
     \begin{bmatrix}-1 \\ 1  \end{bmatrix}\end{align}$, $e_2\approx\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{align}
     \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1  \end{bmatrix}\end{align}$. The corresponding eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ are related to object sizes by $a=k \sqrt{\lambda_1},b=k \sqrt{\lambda_2}$. However $k$ depends on the shape. By testing many combinations of $a,b,\theta$ I can reproduce the  dimensions of the ellipse if  $k\approx4$ and for the rectangle if $k\approx2\sqrt{3}\approx3.46$. How can I derive $k$ from my original data as I do not know beforehand if my object is an ellipse or rectangle?

For completeness I give the covariance matrices of the depicted example:

ellipse (3927 data points):
$\begin{align}  \begin{bmatrix}
390.84770    &  -234.51809 \\
-234.51809   &    390.84770
  \end{bmatrix}\end{align}$

rectangle (4994 data points):
$\begin{align}  \begin{bmatrix}
 518.98143  &    -309.86476\\
-309.86476   &    518.98143
  \end{bmatrix}\end{align}$

Comment: Possibly useful: if $\mu$ denotes the mean coordinates of the figure, then $\lambda_i^2$ is the expected value of $(e_i^T (x-\mu))^2$ among all data points $x$.

Comment: Do you know the shape in advance? Would it be useful to have a way to determine $k$ from the shape?

Comment: The shape is not known in advance. I am interested in the dimensions of the object in the 2 principal directions. As k depends on the shape it would be good to derive k somehow.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear how one could obtain $k$ directly from the data, but here's a relatively simple way to obtain $a,b$. Given your principal components $e_1,e_2$, then it suffices to subtract the maximum and minimum components of the data in these directions.

That is, if $X$ is the matrix whose columns are the pixel coordinates, then
$$
a = \max(e_1^TX) - \min(e_1^TX), \quad 
b = \max(e_2^TX) - \min(e_2^TX), 
$$
where for a vector $v$, $\max(v)$ denotes its maximum entry and $\min(v)$ denotes its minimum entry.

Comment: That's a 'dirty' method but must be accepted in case there is no other way. Actually I assumed that the scaling $k$ can be derived in a more elegant way.

Comment: How do you define max and min from a vector?

Comment: @granularbastard for example, if
$$
v = (-3.5,-1,3,6),
$$
then $\min(v) = -3.5$ and $\max(v) = 6$.